# How to set an icon instead of selected element in spinner for ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-spinner

I want to add a dropdown menu on an action bar using SherlockActionBar. I have found this code in demos:

```
    Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            context, R.array.dropdown_items, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

What I want is that the spinner menu item to be an icon and not the first/selected item in the dropdown. How can I do this? I have tried to set a drawable to the textview in a custom sherlock_spinner_item and also to set text empty but it does not work. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SpinnerAdapter`, the type of adapter used for that widget, allows for specifying custom layouts for both the drop-down layouts and the selected item layouts.

From the illustration you would want to use a different view for the selected item layout which displayed a representative icon of some sort. It's probably best to write your own class that implements `SpinnerAdapter` to achieve this functionality rather than relying on one of the built-in ones (like `ArrayAdapter`).

Answer (score 0):

you should use custom adapter for your spinner like this

```
class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    List<String> stringList;
    Context context;

    public customAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        stringList = objects;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        textView.setText(stringList.get(position));
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return rootView;
    }
```

getDropDownView is for dropDown item and getView is for spinner title.